# how to make nav auto adjsust its menu items using css?

Tags: css, navbar

I have made a menu bar but when i re-size the window the menus leave their position. I want them to auto adjust please suggest how i can achieve this.

here is my fiddle link:

```
[Fiddle][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/c9ssy2dj/
```

Comment: look at your fiddle i just updated it.

Comment: hower i think 9 menupoints are too much. do you want to make it responsive, because i don't understand your question well.

Comment: @Chris Empx yes i want to make it responsive

Comment: ah okay do you know media queries?
you can use them but i think you should make submenu

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/EL0YVdLV can i fix this issue @Chris Empx

Comment: look i postet you a fiddle have fun ;) but please remember that you have it to edit like you need id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this fiddle i made for you: 
http://jsfiddle.net/0w8t31k9/

however you have to edit it because i made it real fast from something i made.

mediaqueries look like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px){
/* css you want to overwrite */
}
```

you can find the documentation and the script here: http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly